# 50% Split traffic to Wordpress subpage as / using nginx and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I would like to create an A/B test scenario where  50% of the traffic is sent to **/** and 50% is sent to **/h2** when trying to access **/**.
It is not an issue that the client will view **/h2** in his browser but I require that every time this client clicks on the homepage he is redirected to **/h2** if he previously saw that version of the homepage.

the only viable option I have come to is cloning the wordpress install and implementing a split proxy infront of both upstreams, however ideally in this scenario I only use 1 upstream.

Comment: nginx can check for the presence of cookies. Make sure WP sets a cookie for **/** upon first visit (based on the assumption both are hosted on the same domain). Then, nginx should be able to detect the presence of this cookie. For further information, check out this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/268633/controlling-nginx-proxy-target-using-a-cookie

Comment: Hi @jawivana if you are open to use 3rd party JS based solution then you may look into free tool by google called Website Optimizer , it keeps track of who visits what and then send users to that version in future and also easily distribute traffic b/w two urls. No need to clone wp install, any two pages can be set as A/B Test https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7012154

Comment: Hi Mohsin, I should have clarified in my original post what was tried, Google Optimizer has been tried out but it seems that  performance degraded considerably and it was not considered viable.